# How to delete single songs in My Music without deleting them from playlists

Tags: macos, itunes, apple-music, playlist

When i create a playlist then i add some songs from Apple music. These songs are added also to "`My Music`" as single songs. When i want to see only complete albums, it is impossible. I need to delete these single songs from "`My Music`" somehow but when i delete a song it also deletes from my playlist

Anyone knows how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you cannot accomplish what you are attempting, and here's why:

The "My Music" section is essentially the master collection of all your music. The Playlists you create are simply sub-sections of that master list.

Comment: They added an option "Add songs to my music when you add them to playlist" it shows that it is possible to separate them. All i want is an option such as "Only show complete albums" in the "My Music" :/

Comment: As far as I know- and I've been using iTunes since day 1, that's never been an option. I've created album playlists as soon as I've imported a CD or purchased an album to guarantee seeing all an albums songs grouped together.

Comment: So check this screenshot, this option came with the latest update -> http://i65.tinypic.com/9039u9.png

Comment: @UtkuDalmaz are you certain that option doesn’t simply add Apple Music and iCloud tracks to my music when you add songs from those sources to a playlist?